# Two arrays inside an array with mongodb/mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I have the following mongodb's query:**

```
db.history.distinct('city',{code: 'A-200-01'})
```

*Then I get this:*

```
[1.0, 2.0]
```

*As you can see it's a simple array.
And i'd like to get an array with two arrays inside of it using a mongoose or mongodb's query. Something like this:*

```
"property": [ [1.0], [2.0] ]
```

This is my first time using mongoose and mongodb's queries so i hope you guys could help me, that would be awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use mongodb or mongoose for that (it is probably impossible). If you need to modify output to different format the node.js itself is most usable tool.

```js
const original = [1.0, 2.0]
const arr = [];
original.forEach(item => arr.push([item]));
console.log({property: arr});
```

Comment: Thank You man! it was easier that i thought